How to fix this html/css code so making a list without new line (indent)?
I am currently trying to make a head of website that every link must be lined up on same line, but ul code always make the list with indent (making new line), I've tried to use my past code or code from other website but nothing seems to work. Can you help me to fix the issue?


@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.header {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -30px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.headimg {
  line-height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 180px;
}

.navi {
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
}
<img src="ECORUM_Logo(png).png" alt="Logo" class="headimg">
<ul class="navi"># Problem is here, I wangt to make this unorder list to be lined in same line, not moving to the next line.
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Events</li>
  <li>Project</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <!-- Inert Image that can contact personal account information -->
</ul>
<hr>




make your li display inline


@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.header{
    background-color : white;
    color : black;
    text-align:center;
    margin: -30px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.headimg{
    line-height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 180px;
}

.navi {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.navi li {
    display: inline; 
    margin-right: 15px; 
}

.navi li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; 
}
<img src="ECORUM_Logo(png).png" alt="Logo" class="headimg">

<ul class="navi">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Events</li>
    <li>Project</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <!-- Insert Image that can contact personal account information -->
</ul>

<hr>




On the ul tag, change the display value to display: flex; or display: inline-block;. For example:
.navi {
    margin-top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
}

